# Parallel method execution with lock .NET C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a xml file that contains all school names with IP Addresses and I am trying to backup each school on a timer interval (i.e. `SchoolFunctions.Backup`).

The problem is that in some cases the backup is too slow and the backup method will be started again while a previous backup is still running...

How can I prevent the execution of `SchoolFunctions.Backup` if it is still running for that school?

```
using (DataTable schools = new DataTable { TableName = "Schools" })
{
     schools.ReadXml(AppSettings.Default.SettingsPath);
     try
     {
         Parallel.ForEach(schools.AsEnumerable(), _opts, row =>
         {
             SchoolFunctions.Backup(row.Field<string>("IPAddress"), row.Field<string>("Name"));
         }
     }

      ...

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would go with Kevins answer

However if you want these backups working independently (not having to wait for all schools to finish), with mostly your current pattern. Then could play with some ideas like this

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string,bool> _dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,bool>();

...

using (DataTable schools = new DataTable { TableName = "Schools" })
{
   schools.ReadXml(AppSettings.Default.SettingsPath);

   try
   {
      Parallel.ForEach(schools.AsEnumerable(), _opts, row =>
      {
         var ipAddress = row.Field<string>("IPAddress");

         // check if there is an ip registered and if its processing
         if (_dict.TryGetValue(ipAddress, out processing) && processing)
            return;

          // its not processing ,so update it
         _dict.AddOrUpdate(ipAddress, true, (s, b) => true);

         SchoolFunctions.Backup(ipAddress , row.Field<string>("Name"));

         // when we are done update processing to false
         _dict.AddOrUpdate(ipAddress, false, (s, b) => false);

      }
   }
}
```

**Note**, there are many ways to do this, however this looks promising. also not tested

Also, you could probably just go with `TryAdd` and `TryRemove` and ignore the value

```
if (!_dict.TryAdd(ipAddress, false))
   return;

SchoolFunctions.Backup(ipAddress , row.Field<string>("Name"));

_dict.TryRemove(ipAddress,out _);
```